# SD-Card doesn't work anymore

Tags: linux, partition, sd-card

I have a SD-Card and it doesn't work anymore. If I enter `dmesg`, this console will show this:

```
[  646.467407] mmc0: new SD card at address d555
[  646.468578] mmcblk0: mmc0:d555 SD032 30.6 MiB 
[  646.474167]  mmcblk0: unknown partition table
```

It shows, that the card has 30.6 MiB, but it has 32 GB. I cannot create a partition and with testdisk could not repair this. testdisk "thinks" it the card has only 972 cylinders.

The damage happens, after I have written a Raspbian image on the card.

Answer (score 0):

- It simply need all partitions to be removed.
- Create New Primary Partition and Format it with All O's.

Comment: How can i remove all partitions? Linux just sees the 32 MiB, not the complete sd drive. And if i want to create a new primary partition, i just could do this on the 32 MB and i get errors.

Comment: Well.. I'm compatible only with Ubuntu and DOS.. If you have one of them, then only I can tell the Process..

Comment: I have Ubuntu..

Answer (score -1):

Then..

Goto Bash..

Search "Disks" and Open it..

.

Select Memory card.. You'll be able to see that 32MB is used and rest is 
Free Memory..

.

Clear the used memory( i.e. 32MB)

.

You'll be with all free space in Memory card..

.

Now Format it.. With all 0's..

Comment: Welcome to the site, Please read Tour of site for answer/question.

Comment: It doesn't work :(. In Disks i see, that my sd card only has 32 MB with format: "unknown". Format with zeros doen't help. I got the message: "Error synchronizing after formatting with type `dos': Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)"

Comment: Are you able to see Free Space of your Memory Card. Well, If yes, then only my method will help else not.

Comment: No, i'm not able to see Free Space.